# Flask returned a controller from url

Tags: python, flask

I'm moving from NodeJS to Flask for various reasons. I use controllers and I can't find how to do it with Flask.

With Express:

```
const testRoute = require('./controller/testController')
...
app.use('/test', testRoute)
```

**Do you know how to do with Flask, I would be very grateful!**

Answer (score 1):

For routing in flask use code like below

```
from manage import application

@application.route('/clear-complete/', methods=['POST'])
def clear_complete():
     ....................
    return redirect('/')
```